# I do not understand how {int a=10; a+=++a-5/3+6*a; System.out.print(a);} outputs 86

Tags: java, operators, expression-evaluation, prefix-operator

I do not understand how

```
{
    int a = 10;
    a += ++a-5/3+6*a;
    System.out.print(a);
}
```

outputs 86

I know that shorthand notation has lower precedence than any of the operator used here so my thought process was to look it as

```
a = a + ++a-5/3+6*a
```

so if I apply precedence `++a` increases value of `a` to 11 and then `5/3=1` and `6*11=66`, so why does it not add the result of this expression (76) to 11 (incremented value of `a`)?

Right now what I understand is that the net of expression `++a-5/3+6*a` which is 76 is added to old value of `a` that is 10. I do not understand why because when we evaluated the expression we did increment the a value but then how can i use the old value now?

Comment: Precedence controls argument grouping, not evaluation order.

Comment: Please can you explain it more to me I have recently started learning JAVA so i do not understand what you mean.

Comment: Think of it as `a = a+(++a)-5/3+6*a`, evaluated left to right. So the first `a` on the RHS still has its original value.

Comment: Vyagh, the Java Language Specification [15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) explains how `+=` is evaluated: "First, the left-hand operand is evaluated ... the value of the left-hand operand is saved and then the right-hand operand is evaluated ... the saved value of the left-hand variable and the value of the right-hand operand are used to perform the binary operation" (I would recommended never to write code like that)

Comment: ( BTW that problem could have been *reduced* to `a += ++a` for a bit of clarity, at least I interpret that `+=` is the *question* here; BTW2 the title is not really a title )

Comment: The article at https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/archive/blogs/ericlippert/precedence-vs-associativity-vs-order has a nice explanation what precedence, associativity and evaluation order mean.

Comment: @ThomasKläger I'm not crazy about that link. For one thing, the phrase 'under-parenthesized expression' is meaningless; secondly, the statement 'parenthesize everything' has no correspondence to how compilers actually work. They don't parenthesize anything in practice.

Answer (score -1):

The expression int a=10; a+=++a-5/3+6*a; System.out.print(a); is a combination of arithmetic operations and assignment.
Let's break it down step by step to understand why it outputs 86:

int a=10;: This initializes the variable a with the value 10.

++a: This is a pre-increment operation, so it increments the value of a by 1, a becomes 11.

5/3: This is an integer division, which results in 1 (because it removes the fractional part).

6*a: This multiplies the current value of a (which is 11) by 6, resulting in 66.

Now, put above operations together:

++a results in a being 11.
5/3 results in 1.
6*a results in 66.
So, the expression ++a-5/3+6*a evaluates to 11 - 1 + 66, which is equal to 76.

Now, let's go back to the original assignment:

a currently has the value 10.
a += 76 is equivalent to a = a + 76, which updates the value of a to 86.
Finally, System.out.print(a) prints the value of a, which is 86.

Comment: "a currently has the value 10" - it starts with value 10, but it has value 11 after evaluating `++a`. The core issue is why the value 10 gets used here instead of 11.

Comment: The code int a=10; a+=++a-5/3+6*a; is not well-defined in Java because it tries to both change and use the value of a in the same step which leads to unpredictable results.
Here, a starts as 10. However, when we do ++a, it changes a to 11. But immediately after that, it uses a as if it's still 10, which is confusing. This behavior is not reliable in Java, and it's best to avoid writing such code for clarity and consistency.

Better would be to follow the below code
int a = 10;
a++;   // Increment a by 1
a = a - 5/3 + 6*a;  // Use incremented value
System.out.print(a);

Comment: @sram21 - Actually, the behavior in Java is 100% totally defined.  The JLS says exactly what happens.   There are no unspecified or unpredictable results ... assuming that the variables are not shared with some other thread.  (The results might be unexpected to someone who doesn't have a deep understanding of the spec, but that is a different thing.  This kind of obscure / code should never be written in a real program ... so normal programmers shouldn't ever encounter it.)

Comment: Now in C (and I think C++) expressions like the above DO have *unspecified* results ... but that is largely a result of the history of the language(s).  They could in theory have fixed that, but only at the cost of *forcing* a lot of legacy code to behave differently with newer compilers.  The potential disruption would have been too high.   Java avoided the problem by strictly specifying the order of evaluation of each step of each operation from day 1.

Comment: Doesn't answer the question that was asked.